# jquery datetimepicker addon am/pm - all pm string as am in the db

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, codeigniter

I am using codeigniter and jquery datetimepicker addon. On my view page I have the datetimepicker  format like

```
$(".traveler").datetimepicker({
        dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
        timeFormat: 'hh:mm tt',
           //other stuff
});
```

In my codeigniter controller action method I have

```
 'arrivaldate' => date('Y-m-d h:i:s a', strtotime($this->input->post('arrivaldate'))), 
 'departuredate' => date('Y-m-d h:i:s a', strtotime($this->input->post('departuredate'))),
```

After saving in the database it looks like this **2013-12-04 08:00:00**

When I read from the database to present, I do this in php

```
date("Y-m-d h:i a",strtotime($myrow['arrivaldate']))
```

When I show it up on my view page again it looks like   2013-12-04 08:00 **am** when it should say 2013-12-04 08:00 **pm**

For some reason I cannot figure out why ? It has to be something with my formats and I have been at it all day. 
Any ideas ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is the hours.  database hours DATETIME is stored in military time.

Change it to

```
date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime($somevariablehere));
```

Now when you stick that in the database it will be correct.

Comment: Thanks so much Kevin ... you are the best...Ohh...Merry Christmas too

Comment: No problem, same to you, if this is the answer, please mark it as the answer.